# How can I enable swiping back effect when setting `onWillPop` method in WillPopScope

Tags: flutter

As the flutter [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/87ca3d52a9d12dea9b6dd91e6efadec4b10536e3/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/route.dart#L209) written. After setting the `onWillPop` method, the swiping effect is disabled.

```
static bool _isPopGestureEnabled<T>(PageRoute<T> route) {
  ...

  // If attempts to dismiss this route might be vetoed such as in a page
  // with forms, then do not allow the user to dismiss the route with a swipe.
  if (route.hasScopedWillPopCallback)
    return false;

  ...

}
```

It seems an intended behavior as discussing in [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203).

So, How can I listen the Navigator.pop event. My need is that it cann't back successfully if some variables are not true.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested creating a custom RouteManager and willPop never get called when doing the swipping back effect.
On the other hand you can call `dispose()` and `deactivate()` on your State to clean your variables before removing the Widget .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My need is that it can only back to previous screen when  all variables  being true